# xlwings add-in not finding python installation

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have been using xlwings on my working laptop and very happy with it.
I have installed it on my desktop, but I struggle to use the add-in functionalities, i.e. calling python from the excel. The error I get is that "I didn't specify a kernel". below an example when trying to import the UDF:

[image: error trace]

If I launch the pythoncode main from spyder that modifies the excel spreadsheet, then I can call any UDF function from excel with no issue. but if I close the excel, I need first to run the python code to sort of create the link between excel and python.

below the xlwings.conf file:

"",""

"USE UDF SERVER","True"

"INTERPRETER",""

"PYTHONPATH",""

"CONDA ENV","base"

"CONDA BASE","C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3"

thank you for the help.

Comment: Not directly related to the issue (I think), but why are you seemingly using your base Conda environment for this?

Comment: @AMC, I only have the base environment. do you see any relation?

Comment: Well it certainly can’t help. Why not create another environment? That’s what they’re meant for, after all!